# Django 'objects.filter()' is not working?

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to filter my products based on the categories but the `Listing.object.filter(category = category)` is not able to filter as desired and return **EMPTY** every time.

On the bottom code at views.py where the function is category with an argument as well category.
Maybe there is some logical error from my side,
any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

Here is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('MC','Mens Clothing'),
    ('WC','Womens Clothing'),
    ('G','Games'),
    ('T','Tech'),
    ('BP','Beauty Products'),
    ('O','Others'),
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.URLField(blank = True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length = 2)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name="winner")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My views.py

```
def index(request):
    items = Listing.objects.filter(availability = True)
    category_list = []
    for d,k in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        category_list.append(k)
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'title': "Active Listing",
        'categories': category_list
    }
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", context)

def categories(request):
    data = []
    for d,k in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        data.append(k)
    context = {
        'categories': data
    }
    return render(request, "auctions/categories.html", context)

def category(request, category):
    data = Listing.objects.filter(category = category, availability = True)
    if len(data) != 0:
        context = {
            'items': data,
            'title': category
        }
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", context)
    else:
        context = {
            'title': "EMPTY",
        }
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", context)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gee57.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change this in your `index.py`

```
for d,k in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    category_list.append(d)
```

Comment: This worked, but I would prefer a full name on the display. I can change the two letters in CATEGORY_CHOICES. But are there any alternatives

Comment: yes, display it inside your template just do ```{{ object.get_category_display }}```